# New Android DB APP

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to write an SQLite database application for an Android Phone. I have an existing db and have created `DataBaseHelper` which `extends SQLiteOpenHelper`.

I am new to android development but I do have experience in windows programming (C++,C#,VB.Net ...)
I am debugging on my phone.

In that helper I check for the existance of the db which fails as I expect.
I the call:

```
/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    String What=myContext.getAssets().toString();
    InputStream myInput=null;
    OutputStream myOutput=null;

    try
    {
        myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME + ".sqlite");// this works
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.d("exception",ex.getMessage() );
    }
    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    try
    {
        myOutput = new FileOutputStream(new File( outFileName + ".sqlite"));
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.d("exception",ex.getMessage() );
    }

    try
    {
        myOutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/DailyReminder.sqlite");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.d("exception",ex.getMessage() );
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    if(myInput!=null && myOutput !=null)
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

all attempts to create the output file fail.

my Manifest has write permissions:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".scrday"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_scrday"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</application>
```

What am I doing wrong?sk/advice?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the stack trace that has the error.

Comment: Have you considered using ORMs like Realm?

Comment: to jyanks
Error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/Calendar2/databases/DailyReminder.sqlite: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I appologize for not getting back earlier but 'Murphy' is alive and well here.

I have been able to UNsatisfactorily get around this error by moving the db location to external storage but I would really much prefer keeping it internal
I also seen 'Permission Denied' error.

Thanks